# Looping through array at command line

Tags: shell, command-line, csh

I'm using the C Shell, and I copy and paste the following commands for each language my site supports (after changing ## to en, es, pt, and so forth):

```
mkdir ##
mv x ##/x
cp -r base ##
echo '<?php $lang="##"; include "settings.php";' > ##/settings.php
/usr/local/bin/php ##/maintenance/update.php
```

Is there a way I can make an array of the languages, and have these steps looped through for each element in the array?

Again, these are being pasted into my terminal and I'm using the C Shell.

Comment: csh? Why would you do that to yourself? (See [Top Ten reasons not to use the C shell](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt), and also the link on the csh tag wiki).

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to create a shell script containing the following;

```
foreach lng (en es pt)
do
  mkdir ${lng}
  mv x ${lng}/x
  cp -r base ${lng}
  echo '<?php $lang="'${lng}'"; include "settings.php";' > ${lng}/settings.php
  /usr/local/bin/php ${lng}/maintenance/update.php
done
```

Note, white space is the default separator for the language list.
I would also fully qualify the path to the directory "path" on line 5.